# Equals Method for assertEquals with String-objects to compare

Tags: java, string, junit, overriding, equals

I want to override the equals method so I can compare two variable-objects if they are equal like an object which has the String "abc" as a variable, and another object which also has the String "abc" as a variable. I need this class in order to manage and parse expressions.

So I want to make a testclass testing wether the variable-objects are equal. I want to override it like that.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return this.variable.equals(((Variable) obj).getVariable());
}
```

Now my problem is that I am not quite sure if this will work later, since I use the equals-method here, which I used before to compare Strings. But since I override it, doesn't that mean that I use the same method now? Or are the variable-strings using the equals-method that is comparing strings? If thats not working, what else should I do to compare String in an overwritten equals method?

Comment: Is this code from the `Variable` class? Is `variable` a field of type `String`?

Comment: Your equals() method violates the contract of Object.equals(), that you should read. equals() should not throw an exception if you pass it an object that is not an instance of Variable. It should return false. If you override equals(), you must also override hashCode(), BTW. I can't understand your question.

Comment: It is probably better to add a new method to compare the `variable` instead of overriding the `equals` operator.  Usually, `equals` is used to compare entire objects, not specific members.

Comment: @Joffrey Yes, its from Variable class.

Comment: @JB Nizet Well my professor told me I can ignore the hashCode() stuff for now. What I mean is: If I override the equals method, and I call a equals method in this method, in order to compare a string like "String1.equals(String2)" , do I use the euqals method that compares Strings or do I use my own method now, since its overwritten.

Comment: Variable.equals() and String.equals() are different methods. If you call equals() on a Variable, Variable.equals() will be executed. If you call equals() on a String, String.equals() will be executed. BTW, you should test your code, that would tell you if the code works as expected or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @JBNizet said, your method, as of right now, could throw a `ClassCastException` if `obj` is not of the right type. You should work on this first:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (!obj instanceof Variable) {
        return false;
    }
    return this.variable.equals(((Variable) obj).getVariable());
}
```

That being said, the newly defined `equals` applies for `Variable` objects, not for strings. **That's why your call to `equals()` within this method will still work**, if that's your question, because it references `String.equals()`, because your `variable` field is a `String` (I guessed), not a `Variable`.

Also, `equals` should be overriden this way only if you mean that you consider `Variable` objects equal when their `variable` field is the same.

Comment: the `obj == null` check is redundant. null is not an instanceof anything.

Comment: Ah I see, that makes sense. Even though that wasnt my question. But indirectly you answered it too. So that means that I can compare the two Strings like that, right? I was afraid that since I override it, I cannot sue the equals method that compares Strings anymore

Comment: @JB Nizet right, if obj is null, its not an instance anyways.

Comment: @DennisvonEich what you overrode is only the `equals()` method for the `Variable` class, so you're fine using `equals()` on a `String`, this won't call the overriden method.